# df.column.any() < 1 giving True when not a single value is less than 1 python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting a really strange boolean result from my pandas Dataframe when running a query to see if any values in a particular column are less than 1. My `df` looks as such with columns `marketcap` and `assets`:

```
     marketcap       assets
0   11730364.0   36675000.0
1   12288758.0   36838000.0
2   13033591.0   37314000.0
3   16235899.0   39775000.0
4   14888920.0   40114000.0
5   14237392.0   38979000.0
6   13474342.0   38166000.0
7   12562067.0   45970000.0
8   13896045.0   45619000.0
9   15347038.0   46759000.0
10  14044865.0   46744000.0
11  14361107.0   49749000.0
12  14317742.0   49425000.0
13  17608963.0   49592000.0
14  19412627.0   49624000.0
15  26690171.0   51732000.0
16  27470803.0   53220000.0
17  27674325.0   52500000.0
18  37433151.0   53103000.0
19  53900763.0   53811000.0
20  58714659.0   54113000.0
21  47562777.0   55545000.0
22  51949184.0   54622000.0
23  40667196.0   56321000.0
24  35314293.0   56854000.0
25  39607768.0   56221000.0
26  44291558.0   56401000.0
27  45258054.0   59492000.0
28  45072190.0   60893000.0
29  56131139.0   60376000.0
30  45072190.0   60509000.0
31  43852174.0   67544000.0
32  44607528.0   67333000.0
33  51205725.0   66435000.0
34  52042116.0   67265000.0
35  48083198.0   70056000.0
36  43083437.0   68674000.0
37  42748881.0   67977000.0
38  39496249.0   68755000.0
39  41985349.0  102904000.0
```

Clearly all the values in the column `marketcap` are well above 1 yet for the following code:

```
df.marketcap.any() <= 1
```

It results a result of `True`. Could someone explain this to me as I can't understand why this is True and what it thinks is less than 1.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

*why this is True and what it thinks is less than 1.*

You are doing:

```
df.marketcap.any() <= 1
```

`df.marketcap.any()` does evaluate to `True` as you have one or more non-zero elements in marketcap, so comparison is

```
True <= 1
```

which does hold `True` as in python when `True` and `False` are used for arithmetic it does have same effect as using `1` and `0` respectively. Note that their usage is not limited to comparisons - for example you can do `True+True+True` and you will get `3`.